# Unable to print Image control which is inside of grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image

**This is `jquery` Code ::**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintElem(elem) {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) {
        alert(document.getElementById('<%=imgphoto.ClientID%>').src);
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'Customer Details', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Customer Details</title>');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');

        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
        return true;
        }
    </script>
```

**This is my Source Code ::**

```
<div id="mydiv">
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-size: large">
                    Customer Document Details
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 20px; width: 140px">
                    <b>Photo</b>
                </td>
                <td style="font-weight: 700">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgphoto" runat="server" AlternateText="Image Not Available" class="imgresize"
                        ForeColor="Red" Height="85px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Empty.png" Width="109px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
    </div>
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="PrintElem('#mydiv')"
        CausesValidation="False" />
```

**My problem ::**

I am trying to print all contents of `div tag` on button `OnClientClick="PrintElem('#mydiv')"` but I am getting all contents of div tag except of Image.So please help me to get Image control while print a page.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code like this

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function PrintElem(elem) {
            Popup($(elem).html());
        }

        function Popup(data) {
            alert(document.getElementById('<%=imgphoto.ClientID%>').src);
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'Customer Details', 'height=400,width=600');
            mywindow.document.write(data);

            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();
            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

**Source Code:**

```
<div id="mydiv">
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-size: large">
                    Customer Document Details
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 20px; width: 140px">
                    <b>Photo</b>
                </td>
                <td style="font-weight: 700">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgphoto" runat="server" AlternateText="Image Not Available" class="imgresize"
                        ForeColor="Red" Height="85px" ImageUrl="Desert.jpg" Width="109px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="PrintElem('#mydiv')"
        CausesValidation="False" />
```

Working perfectly.

i above code not worked. please refer another one from below URL
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/08/jquery-print-div-content-with-css-using.html'
its also working

Comment: sorry friends in your case it may running perfectly but here is same problem.it may due to i am assigning run time ImageUrl to image control.so please try this code with run time path.

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar i put that image in to the root directory and do the same.... working.....

Comment: @ Biby Augustine  it does't consult with same directory.I am retrieving  image path from the database and then assigning to image control.so i May getting this problem so please try it.

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar i tired like you said... i getting the exact answer.... please avoid adding <html></html><body></body><title></title> writes in javascript.

Comment: @ Biby Augustine as you are telling i tried it but it is not working it my case.do you have any other solution to solve my problem.

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar which browser you are used to test.. mine is latest Firefox.

Comment: just go here and try this...... its also working for me.. http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/08/jquery-print-div-content-with-css-using.html